# About ui-router.How ui-sref in ui-sref takes different template?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

the html like this:

`<li class="list-group-item" ui-sref="contacts.detail({id:4})">
    <span class="badge"  ui-sref="contacts.selected">14</span>
    Cras justo odio
</li>`

the `contacts.selected` will redirect to `contacts.detail`'s template.
how to render it's own template

Answer (score 0):

As i see, when you click `.badge` it triggers `contacts.selected` sref, but javascript event bubbles up the dom tree and comes to parent `li` element and triggers it's `contact.detail` sref a little bit after the first sref trigger.

So you should decouple `ui-sref`'s to different elements and it'll work fine.

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <span class="badge" ui-sref="contacts.selected">14</span>
    <span ui-sref="contacts.detail({id:4})">Cras justo odio</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Yeah，this is also success.And a smart method!!!But if use the method as I say,is it a error use?

Comment: No, i don't think it's an error or invalid syntax. But you don't get what you want by doing so, aren't you?